# How to create a new folder in Bonita web server?

Tags: tomcat, webserver, bonita

I'm new to Bonita BPM.

I created a variable to link to a local directory. But it didn't work because of the web browser security restriction. 
I changed the logic that once I create a new directory on the web server, I can link the directory and show what is inside. 
Is this a right logic?

I tried to create a test folder in a physical path under the tomcat server. 
But file:/// didn't work as well.

I would like to create a folder and upload files from a local directory.
Is it possible to create a new directory in Bonita web server?

If possible, I would like to connect with the address like "file:///localhost:8888/bonita/archives/"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to create a folder and upload files from a local
>   directory.

According to your requirement to read files from a local directory, my recommendation would be the following:

1. [Set up a local FTP server](https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/download_1.1.1.html) and you can place your folders and/or files under the root.
2. In the BPMN, create a groovy script to [connect](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/connect-and-login-to-a-ftp-server) to this local FTP server and [download](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example) the files. Create a byte array from the inputstream of the file downloaded.
3. You can attach this byte array as a document to the case using [attachDocument](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/javadoc/api/7.0/org/bonitasoft/engine/api/DocumentAPI.html#attachDocument(long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D)) function in Process API using

   apiAccessor.processAPI.attachDocument(processInstanceId,documentVarName,fileName,fileType,byteArrayFromInputStream);
4. You can view these case documents in the form

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems a little bit difficult for me, but I will try to find a way.